# push another VC in popover after dropbox/facebook login

Tags: ios, dropbox, pushviewcontroller

I have an iOS app that will list photos from 3rd party storage (dropbox, Facebook) to a popover, where do you put the pushViewController to push another ContentDetailVC for the 3rd party content (dropbox or Facebook) upon completing the 3rd party authentication using their SDK?

so the sequence is like this

click setting icon -> open up a popover showing menu items -> click one menu item (dropbox) -> it opens up 3rd party (dropbox login modalVC) -> login was successful -> popover's NavController push the dropbox DetailVC to the popover. ideally, I'd like to keep the popover still visible but pushed to the new VC once 3rd party login was successful.

I currently put the login method in the DetailVC's ViewDidLoad, so the 3rd party loginVC shows correctly, but once that loginVC dismiss, my DetailVC content cannot be refreshed as ViewDidLoad is already done...

Answer (score 0):

do your refresh stuff in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. These will be called every time the view appears (when the DetailVC is pushed or a view is popped to reveal your DetailVC)

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
[((UINavigationController*)self.parentViewController) pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code for finding the class method to reload the ViewController in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
   //write the code for finding out your respective ViewController and then the method to reload the view controller.
}
```

This will definitely solve your problem as it has helped we with the similar situation.